# Record lock issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking, record

Since a couple of days, I've been experiencing a MySQL issue in a large table (over 800,000 records). I've determined so far that the issue so far seems to be with 2 records, s I'm unable to update them. When I run the failing update statement, this is what I see.

How do I fix this? Things like SHOW PROCESSLIST; show nothing else. Flushing tables also did not seem to help yet.

```
Trx id counter 34362695
Purge done for trx's n:o < 34362695 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 283740434665792, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283740434664240, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283740434663464, not started
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 34362692, ACTIVE 10 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 8, OS thread handle 9000, query id 52534 localhost ::1 root updating
update users set level = -2 where userid = 5747443
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 10 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 113290 page no 2534 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table `xyz`.`users` trx id 34362692 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
```

It eventually leads to

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

It's interesting to note that the data of the record still shows a value for an already dropped column.